# Need to check results after page refresh 5 times

Tags: java, selenium

Hello I am trying to automate this test case where i need to first search an item, then store the count of the total results, then store the first 5 counts from the result and then refresh the page 5 times. At every refresh i need to verify that the results are same, and pass the case if and if only after each refresh results are same, else fail the result. Below is the my code which i am trying, using if and for loop, the get.attribute() is giving stale element exception. Stuck here as how to get it done.

```
<div class="ui-lib-sidebar-grid__content">
<div class="ui-lib-margin-b_md ui-lib-margin-t_md totalResultsText">
    <p class="totalResultsText">Showing 1-10 of 316 results</p>
</div>
<div class="" style="">
    <div class="ui-lib-category-list ui-lib-category-list-dummy">
        <div class="ui-lib-category-list-item">
            <div class="ui-lib-category-list-item__content">
                <div class="ui-lib-category-list-item__content-header">
                    <div class="ui-lib-category-list-item-type">
                        <svg version="1.1" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" preserveAspectRatio="xMinYMid slice" data-key="" class="ui-lib-category-list-item-type__icon ui-lib-category-list-item-type__icon_service ui-lib-icon" width="24" height="24" viewBox="0 0 24 24">
                            <title></title>
                            <circle cx="12" cy="12" r="12" fill-rule="evenodd"></circle>
                        </svg><span class="ui-lib-category-list-item-type__label">Service</span></div>
                </div><a class="ui-lib-link ui-lib-link_default" target="_self" aria-label="Request for Collection and Transfer of Green Waste from Residential Areas" rel="noopener noreferrer" href="https://www.tamm.abudhabi/en/aspects-of-life/environmentagriculture/Waste-Management/WasteCollectionandTransportation/RequestforCollectionandTransferofGreenWastefromResidentialAreas"><h4 class="ui-lib-link__heading ui-lib-bold">Request for Collection and Transfer of Green Waste from Residential Areas</h4></a>
                <div class="ui-lib-category-list-item__description">Through this service, you can request the collection and transfer of green wastes from residential areas.</div>
                <div class="ui-lib-category-list-item__tags">
                    <div tabindex="0" role="button" class="ui-lib-tag ui-lib-tag_size-default ui-lib-tag_grey ui-lib-tag_hoverable ui-lib-tag_clickable"><span class="ui-lib-tag__text">Abu Dhabi Waste Management Center</span></div>
                    <div tabindex="0" role="button" class="ui-lib-tag ui-lib-tag_size-default ui-lib-tag_blue ui-lib-tag_hoverable ui-lib-tag_clickable"><span class="ui-lib-tag__text">Expat</span></div>
                    <div tabindex="0" role="button" class="ui-lib-tag ui-lib-tag_size-default ui-lib-tag_blue ui-lib-tag_hoverable ui-lib-tag_clickable"><span class="ui-lib-tag__text">Visitor</span></div>
                    <div tabindex="0" role="button" class="ui-lib-tag ui-lib-tag_size-default ui-lib-tag_blue ui-lib-tag_hoverable ui-lib-tag_clickable"><span class="ui-lib-tag__text">Emirati</span></div>
                </div>
   
    List<WebElement> TotalSearchResults = driver.
    findElements(By.xpath("//div[@class='ui-lib-sidebar-grid__content']//div[contains(@class,'ui-lib-category-list ui-lib-category-list-dummy')]/div"));
    int Total_Count = TotalSearchResults.size();

List<WebElement> FirstFive = driver.
            findElements(By.xpath("//div[@class='ui-lib-sidebar-grid__content']//div[contains(@class,'ui-lib-category-list ui-lib-category-list-dummy')]/div//a")).
            stream().limit(5).collect(Collectors.toList());
    int     First_Five = FirstFive.size();
    System.out.println(FirstFive.size());

    List <WebElement> After_refresh = driver.
            findElements(By.xpath("//div[@class='ui-lib-sidebar-grid__content']//div[contains(@class,'ui-lib-category-list ui-lib-category-list-dummy')]/div//a")).
            stream().limit(5).collect(Collectors.toList());

    //Thread.sleep(10000);

        driver.navigate().refresh();
        Thread.sleep(10000);
        for (WebElement webElement : FirstFive){
            String link = webElement.getAttribute("href");
            System.out.println(link);
```

Answer (score 1):

I still didn't understand your complete code. But on seeing the exception, you need to find the elements all again.

After you have refreshed, the `FirstFive` elements are no longer attached to DOM. So, after refresh, if you want to get the `FirstFive` elements, you need to again find the elements.

Something like this:

```
//Just retained the locator which you have mentioned as it is
    By byCategoryElements = By.xpath("//div[@class='ui-lib-sidebar-grid__content']//div[contains(@class,'ui-lib-category-list ui-lib-category-list-dummy')]/div//a");

    @Test
    public void refreshValidation5Times() throws Exception {
        WebDriverManager.chromedriver().setup();
        WebDriver driver = new ChromeDriver();
        List<String> firstFiveData = getFirstFiveData(driver);
        for(int counter = 0; counter < 5; counter ++) {
            driver.navigate().refresh();
            Thread.sleep(10000); //10 seconds is a huge time. Instead try to wait for some element presence.
            List<String> nextDataSet = getFirstFiveData(driver);
            if(! compareTwoLists(firstFiveData,nextDataSet)) {
                throw new Exception("Data is not matching after refresh");
            }
        }
        System.out.println("Data is matching after 5 refresh attempts");
    }

    public List<String> getFirstFiveData(WebDriver driver) {
        return driver
                .findElements(byCategoryElements)
                .stream()
                .limit(5)
                //From your above code, it seems you want to validate href data
                .map(we -> we.getAttribute("href"))
                .collect(Collectors.toList());
    }

    public boolean compareTwoLists(List<String> list1, List<String> list2) {
        return list1.stream().allMatch(list1Data -> list2.contains(list1Data))
                && list2.stream().allMatch(list2Data -> list1.contains(list2Data));
    }
```

**Edit 1:**
You need to traverse the FirstFive to get the link and print. Modified the above code. Please check it now. Please note that, what am mentioning here is just an outline. Request you to please modify it as per your need.

**Edit 2:**
Updated as per your latest comment. Is this what you are expecting.

Comment: Your above code is giving error for String link = String link = webElement.getAttribute("href"); Unable to resolve symbol WebElement

Comment: @ghufranhaq Modified the code, please check this.

Comment: Actually what i need to do is, to verify the results after every refresh. The total number of browser refreshes should be 5. If the results are same after each refresh the case will pass, else it will fail. I tried to do it but i don't think my code is doing it. Need help and a bit of explanation how can i achieve it. I have just started automation so i am totally confused here. I hope this clears the confusion.

Comment: @ghufranhaq Please let me know the locator that has the search results? Is it going to be <p class="totalResultsText">Showing 1-10 of 316 results</p>? So, 316 is the results count. This count should remain same upon refreshing it 5 times. Is that your requirement?

Comment: Well, the requirement is there is a total of 316 results, of which 10 are displayed on the page due to pagination. So I need to store the total results that is 10 and then store the First five results from that Total of 10 results. Need to compare it after every refresh. So the assertion would be based on the text not on the count to make sure the results are the same. Once the 5 iterations of refresh are done and passed the case if the results are the same, else the case will fail if the results are different. I hope the requirement is clear now.

Comment: @ghufranhaq please check now.